# How to change data in the userInfo when using NSTimer?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nstimer, userinfo

I use NSTimer to repeat a function every 1 second. I use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` method's `userInfo` parameter. I need to update data in this `userInfo`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "minus:", userInfo: ["number": 100], repeats: true)
}

func minus(timer: NSTimer) {
    var userInfo = timer.userInfo as! Dictionary <String, Int>
    println(userInfo["number"]!)
    userInfo["number"] = userInfo["number"]! - 1
}
```

I hope what is printed is 100 99 98 97. But I get 100 100 100 100 when the code is run.

When the function `minus` runs for the first time, I think I have changed userInfo's data from 100 to 99. But `userInfo`'s data is still 100 when function `minus` runs for the second time.

How can I update `userInfo`'s data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised it isn't a build error / crash as the `userInfo` is read-only.

You could make it an `NSMutableDictionary` so you aren't changing the `userInfo` pointer you're just changing the contents of the object it points at, but I'd say really you should just use an instance variable...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the userInfo object in a timer. userInfo is a readonly property. So the obvious workaround is that you store a mutable object as the userInfo. For example NSMutableDictionary* or your own class.

However, you started with an immutable NSDictionary, and then you converted it to a Swift dictionary. Don't do that. You need direct access to the object that was stored, that is an NSMutableDictionary.